# Why can't I rename master before making a first commit?

Tags: git, git-branch

I stumbled upon the following error when trying to rename my master branch (git branch -M main):"

```
error: refname refs/heads/master not found
```

After making my first commit, I was able to rename my branch without any issues. At this point, I wondered why I couldn't rename the master branch.

The error message suggests that there is no reference "master". This is logical because there are no commits for it to point to. However, it's worth noting that the branch "master" itself exists, as demonstrated by the fact that I can run "`git branch --show-current`".

**So what is happening? Why does Git require a reference when renaming a branch? and is there a way to rename master before making a first commit?** (besides:
[git: rename local branch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382986/git-rename-local-branch-failed#comment126788100_64205437))

---

Additionaly:

The following comment suggests that Git is in a 'detached head state,' but I find the explanation unclear.
[git: rename local branch failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18382986/git-rename-local-branch-failed#comment86159532_18383042)

I thought of detached head as "HEAD is not pointing to a branch (but maybe a commit)".
But in my case not only HEAD but also master are not pointing *anywhere*.

---

**Edit:**

using git < v.2.30.0

Comment: You can use `git switch -c newBranchName` to "switch to" a new branch. Once you commit that commit will be on the new branch. Note that both `master` and `newBranchName` don't really "exist" in any shape other than their name due to there not being a commit for them to point to. `.git/refs/HEAD` will point to their names, but their names will not reference anything.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, but when master is named. Why can't I simply change the name? 
And when I would switch to 'main' and would commit here, master would still exist?

Comment: Or use `git init --initial-branch=main ...`

Comment: Some useful suggestions here https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24104 beside committing to resolve

Comment: @RichardSmith, my question focuses more on the 'why' rather than the 'how'?

Comment: What does "changing the name" of master even mean when it doesn't point to anything? Creating a new branch with a new name is indistinguishable from renaming master as long as nothing is commited. Before the first commit `master` is nothing other than a string in `.git/refs/HEAD` (try yourself: create a new repo and grep for `master` on it, make sure to include the `.git` directory). The comment I showed you changes that string. So for all intents and purposes that's "renaming master".

Comment: When a git repo is first created _there are no commits, no trees, no blobs, and **no branches**_. You cannot rename it because it doesn't exist. Git just "assumes" what the initial branch name will be and calls it that when the first commit is made.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Ok so `git switch -c newBranchName` doesn't really create a new branch (or master is removed in process - either would result in the same outcome as you stated). And the only trace of the name is the [...]/.git/HEAD file? But why wouldn't `git branch --move`  just do the same thing rather than printing an Error?

Comment: `git branch --move` tries to rename a file in `.git/refs/heads` (i.e. "a branch"), which doesn't exist at that point. I know it's confusing that "what's the current branch" is a question that can be answered without there *existing* any actual branches, but I guess it's a weirdness in the model that's been introduced to not require the initial commit to also declare a branch name to which to commit.

Comment: @Doku Why would you want to change the name? It's not practical. Create a different branch and switch to that.

Comment: What Git version are you using? I can rename the initial branch even before committing.

Comment: @Caleb, pure curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't I rename master before making a first commit?

Because you're using a version of Git older than [2.30.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.38.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.30.0.txt). Since then you should be able to rename the initial branch before making any commits. For example:

```
/
$ git --version
git version 2.30.0.windows.1

/
$ git init
hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
hint:
hint:   git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
hint:
hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
hint:
hint:   git branch -m <name>
Initialized empty Git repository in /

/ (master)
$ git branch -m main

/ (main)
$
```

This change was introduced in [commit cfaff3aac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34) (Dec 11, 2020) and merged in [commit 772bdcd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/772bdcd4296b259d52aafb0badd79872e9db3bb3) (Dec 18, 2020). It first appeared in [tag v2.30.0-rc1](https://github.com/git/git/tree/v2.30.0-rc1).

Comment: Note, I confirmed this didn't work in Git version 2.29, so this capability was in fact introduced in 2.30.

Comment: You are right! But I couldn't find the change inside gits Release Notes. Are there any Changelogs other than [githubusercontent RelNotes/2.30.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.30.0.txt)?

Comment: @Doku I couldn't either. When I have some time I'll dig into the code and see if I can find it.

Comment: @Doku I updated the answer with the commits that brought in the change. Perhaps that's the *best* kind of documentation. 

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me out! @TTT